ParseError syntax error, unexpected token "endif", expecting end of file
Estoy intentando que muestre un formulario si es una ruta u otro si es otra este es mi codigo:
@if($request->is('nuevoJuego'){
  <form action="{{ route('nuevoJuego') }}" method="POST">
    @csrf
    <input type="hidden" name="juego_id" value="{{ $juego_id }}">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Nombre" name="name">
    <select name="juego_id" id="">
      <option value="{{ $juego->id }}"> {{ $juego->jugadores_minimos }} </option>
    </select>
    <select name="" id="">
      <option value="{{ $juego->id }}"> {{ $juego->jugadores_maximos }} </option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
  </form>
}
@elseif($request->is('nuevaPartida'){
  <form action="{{ route('nuevaPartida') }}" method="POST">
    @csrf
    <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
  </form>
}
@endif

el error que me tira al acceder a la ruta es:
ParseError    PHP 8.3.6    10.48.25   syntax error, unexpected token "endif", expecting end of file.
Es como si sobrara el @endif, o sestuviera cerrado otra vez antes de llegar al @endif, soy muy nuevo en esto, asi que posiblemente sea algo de la sintaxis que se me escapa, algún cierre que haga mal, pero no lo veo,¿alguien puede ayudarme?

¿Conocés la sintaxis de Blade? Solo por si acaso.

Si, estoy siguiendo cursos de laravel 9, que del 10 al 9 no se llevan diferencia, y usan eso que he puesto, pero seguro, ya no estoy de nada; si es asi, o es con "has" o de otra forma, ya he visto varias, y probe otra, con el mismo resultado.

¿Con las llaves ({})?

En el formulario?

Tus IF están mal cerrados, eso es todo.
Trata de poner de mejor manera la condición y luego las llaves, para que notes el problema a la vista. De todos modos, el error es específico.
Por el comentario de Padaleiana, me doy cuenta que, efectivamente, has confundido el uso del IF en Blade, cuando este se usa con llaves.
@if($request->is('nuevoJuego'))  <!-- Faltaba parentesis de cierre -->
{ <!-- Abrir correctamente el IF -->
  <!-- Aca va el codigo del IF -->
} <!-- Cerrar correctamente el IF -->
@elseif($request->is('nuevaPartida'))  <!-- Faltaba parentesis de cierre -->
{ <!-- Abrir correctamente el ELSEIF -->
  <!-- Aca va el codigo del ELSEIF -->
} <!-- Cierre del ELSEIF -->
@endif <!-- Cierre final del IF -->

Para usarlo sin llaves { }, tendrías que corregir el mismo problema original, y no usar las llaves.
@if($request->is('nuevoJuego'))
    <!-- Aca va el codigo del IF -->
@elseif($request->is('nuevaPartida'))
    <!-- Aca va el codigo del ELSEIF -->
@endif <!-- Cierre final del @IF -->


Eso era, crei que cerre el parentesis, pero no estaba cerrado, gracias.

Mientras aprendas, hazlo del modo que sea lo más entendible para ti. Y cuando aparesca un error, no temas en buscarlo directamente y ver que dice la gente del error. Siempre un ParseError PHP -  syntax error es que has escrito algo mal, y solo hay que encontrar que es.

Es una práctica un poco rara utilizar objetos de request en una plantilla. Deberías mandar otra variable desde tu controller para elegir el formulario, sino estás haciendo que una vista dependa de una petición. Dado que vienes de un controller(y por tanto de una ruta) la plantilla debe saber ya sin preguntarlo que formulario debe entrar. Si lo necesitas puedes usar la herencia de Blade, y sobreescribir el bloque que muestra el formulario con el que tiene tu plantilla.

Cierto, y en programación hay que andar con mil ojos...y de momento solo tengo dos, aun no me da por injertarme un par extra...xD

Recuerda marcar la respuesta como correcta por favor
